# C# List of class instances

Tags: c#

I am not new to programming but I am very new to C#. I am trying to populate a list with instances of a class.

I would expect the following piece of code to display numbers 0 to 9 in the console but instead it repeats 9 ten times. Clearly I am doing something wrong.

I am suspecting that adding "a" to the list simply adds a reference to "a", and not a new instance of class1. I am not sure what I should be adding though. What would be the correct syntax to add a new instance of class1 to the list?

Thanks in advance for any answer!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<class1> iList = new List<class1>();
            class1 a = new class1();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {

                iList.Add(a);
                iList[i].var1 = i;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < iList.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Console.Write("var1 of " + i + ": " + iList[i].var1 + "\r\n");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class class1
    {
        public int var1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `iList.Add(new class1());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are adding the same object over and over again, and that's it's causing that all ten items are pointing to the same object.

When you add an object to a list, you are not creating a new object. You are adding a reference to the object you are adding. In this example, you are adding the same reference 10 times. Thus, every time you access the `var1` property, you are re writing the same value.

Then, when you are looping over the list (that will contain 10 references) all this references are pointing to the same object.

The instance of class1 should be in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    class1 a = new class1();
    iList.Add(a);
    iList[i].var1 = i;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! I suspected that I was simply referencing the same object 10 times instead of creating a new one, but I didn't know how to create a new one. I am sitll having a hard time grasping what difference does it make. Is it correct to say that by placing the declaration inside the loop, at the end of each loop the "a" instance is destroyed, so on the next loop while the name "a" is the same, it's a new instance?

Comment: It will not actually be *destroyed*. It will remain in memory, because the list is pointing to it. What's going to happen is that `a` variable (reference) will be now pointing to another object.

Comment: So, in practice, the list is simply a catalog of pointers to the ten instances, it doesn't contain anything but the refrences in it's own structure. Is that corrent?

Comment: I'd suggest `iList.Add(new class1())` though.

Comment: Yes, maybe adding an inline new object would be the best approach. But for explaining and displaying purposes, doing one thing at a time helps to understand what's going on :)

Comment: Oh, actually I like this inline declaration, seems so elegant :D Memory wise, is there a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Which programming language you are familiar to? In normal popular language objects from classes are referent data types. If you add twice the same instance in a list, changing a field in that instance will reflect both elements in the list.

In your particular case you are adding only one instance 10 times. On the last iteration you do change the value of the field to `9` which reflects all items in the array pointing to that instance.

If you want to achieve the desired behavior, you need to add new instances of the class. E.g. to create it in the loop, not outside it.